# Why does the ComboBox do not refresh to new value

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I still learn how to create GUI. First, i click `JComboBox cb[0]` and pick management and all the rest `JComboBox` seem follow the if statement but after i change the`JComboBox cb[0]` to other than `management`, other `JComboBox` don't follow the if statement. The others `JComboBox` still stuck to management if statement.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class testGUI {
    JFrame f[]=new JFrame[10];
    JPanel pn[]=new JPanel[10];
    JLabel l[]=new JLabel[10];
    JButton bt[]=new JButton[10];
    JTextField tf[]=new JTextField[10];
    JTextArea ts[]=new JTextArea[10];
    JOptionPane op[]=new JOptionPane[10];
    JComboBox cb[]=new JComboBox[10];
    JRadioButton rb[]=new JRadioButton[10];
    ButtonGroup bg[]=new ButtonGroup[10];

    public testGUI() {
        f[4]=new JFrame("Register User");
        f[4].setDefaultCloseOperation(f[0].EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f[4].setSize(630,600);
        f[4].setResizable(false);
        f[4].setLayout(null);

        l[0]=new JLabel("Matric Number");
        l[0].setBounds(100,20,100,30);
        f[4].add(l[0]);
        tf[0]=new JTextField();
        tf[0].setBounds(220,25,200,30);
        f[4].add(tf[0]);

        l[1]=new JLabel("Job");
        l[1].setBounds(50,100,80,30);
        f[4].add(l[1]);
        String job[]= {"Management","Staff","Student"};
        cb[0]=new JComboBox(job);
        cb[0].setBounds(110,100,100,30);
        f[4].add(cb[0]);
        cb[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String s=(String) cb[0].getSelectedItem();
                if(s.equals("Management")) {
                    cb[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            String m=(String) cb[2].getSelectedItem();
                            if(m.equals("Car")) {
                                cb[3].removeAllItems();
                                cb[3].addItem("Management");
                                cb[3].addItem("Car");
                                f[4].repaint();
                                System.out.println("eee");
                            }
                            else if(m.equals("Bike")) {
                                cb[3].removeAllItems();
                                cb[3].addItem("Management");
                                cb[3].addItem("Bike");
                                f[4].repaint();
                                System.out.println("hhh");
                            }
                            else {
                                cb[3].removeAllItems();
                                cb[3].addItem("N/A");
                                f[4].repaint();
                                System.out.println("fff");
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                }
                else if(s.equals("Staff")) {
                    cb[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            String m=(String) cb[2].getSelectedItem();
                            if(m.equals("Car")) {
                                cb[3].removeAllItems();
                                cb[3].addItem("Staff");
                                cb[3].addItem("Car");
                                f[4].add(cb[3]);
                                f[4].repaint();
                                System.out.println("aaa");
                            }
                            else if(m.equals("Bike")) {
                                cb[3].removeAllItems();
                                cb[3].addItem("Staff");
                                cb[3].addItem("Bike");
                                cb[3].setBounds(450,200,100,30);
                                f[4].add(cb[3]);
                                f[4].repaint();
                                System.out.println("www");
                            }
                            else {
                                cb[3].removeAllItems();
                                cb[3].addItem("N/A");
                                f[4].add(cb[3]);
                                f[4].repaint();
                                System.out.println("qqq");
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                }
                else {
                    cb[2].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            String m=(String) cb[2].getSelectedItem();
                            if(m.equals("Car")) {
                                cb[3].removeAllItems();
                                cb[3].addItem("Car");
                                f[4].add(cb[3]);
                                f[4].repaint();
                                System.out.println("ooo");
                            }
                            else if(m.equals("Bike")) {
                                cb[3].removeAllItems();
                                cb[3].addItem("Bike");
                                f[4].add(cb[3]);
                                f[4].repaint();
                                System.out.println("lll");
                            }
                            else {
                                cb[3].removeAllItems();
                                cb[3].addItem("N/A");
                                f[4].add(cb[3]);
                                f[4].repaint();
                                System.out.println("mmm");
                            }
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            } 
        }); 

        l[2]=new JLabel("No. of Vehicle");
        l[2].setBounds(350,100,100,30);
        f[4].add(l[2]);
        String vcNo[]= {"1","2","3"};
        cb[1]=new JComboBox(vcNo);
        cb[1].setBounds(450,100,100,30);
        f[4].add(cb[1]);

        l[3]=new JLabel("Vehicle Type");
        l[3].setBounds(80,150,100,30);
        f[4].add(l[3]);
        String vcType[]= {"Car","Bike","Bus","Lorry"};
        cb[2]=new JComboBox(vcType);
        cb[2].setBounds(70,200,100,30);
        f[4].add(cb[2]);

        l[4]=new JLabel("Plate No");
        l[4].setBounds(290,150,100,30);
        f[4].add(l[4]);
        tf[1]=new JTextField();
        tf[1].setBounds(250,200,130,30);
        f[4].add(tf[1]);

        l[5]=new JLabel("Parking Lot");
        l[5].setBounds(460,150,100,30);
        f[4].add(l[5]);
        cb[3]=new JComboBox();
        /*String pLot[]= {"Management","Staff","Car","Bike"};
        cb[3]=new JComboBox(pLot);*/
        cb[3].setBounds(450,200,100,30);
        f[4].add(cb[3]);

        bt[0]=new JButton("REGISTER");
        bt[0].setBounds(230,470,150,80);
        bt[0].setVisible(true);
        bt[0].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        f[4].add(bt[0]);

        f[4].setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        new testGUI();
    }
}
```

I already tried use `f[4].repaint()` to refresh the frame but nothing happen.

Comment: Don't keep adding `ActionListener`s` within `ActionListener`s, as the name applies "adding" will append the `ActionListener` to the list of listeners which will notified when the action occurs. So, each time your trigger a new action, you're add more listeners to the component, which will be trigged in reverse order, so the first listener will be the last notified, which is why it doesn't seem to work after the first change

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.